# Freeform encoding attachment URL

Tags: solspace-freeform, html-entities

Recently upgrade a site to 2.9.2 and Freeform 4.2.1 PHP 5.3.28 and all is going well until we spotted this oddity.

The Notifications templates setup for the customer and admin emails use this:

```
{attachments} <a href="{fileurl}">{filename}</a> {/attachments}
```

This used to link back to the file but now for some reason it's encoding the URL

```
*CURRENT*
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com.au%2Fmedia%2Fpublic_submissions%2FCIM%2Fmyfilename.jpg

*OLD*
http://www.example.com.au/media/public_submissions/CIM/myfilename.jpg
```

I've no idea what could be causing this, I tried a simple `{exp:freeform:entries}` tag and it did spit out the filename but no full URL so I cant even test where the fault is.

Seriously, I'm looking for a needle in a haystack here any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd also like an answer to this. I hadn't realised that this was happening because the recent freeform forms I've built have been set to attach the files to the notification email rather than linking to them, but when I ran a test (thinking I'd be able to throw a simple solution over to you) I found the same issue. Except that mine seemed to be even worse; with attachments disabled and the link set up in the notification template (with allow HTML 'yes'), the link, when it arrives in Apple Mail, begins with x-webdoc://409C5417-105C-40E2-B029-F86F9B55CC36/   which of course is a mess.

Comment: Start here:

/system/expressionengine/third_party/freeform/libraries/Freeform_notifications.php

starts on line 52.

I would be curious about what the $template_data looks like on line 201:

ob_start(); var_dump($template_data); $test = ob_get_clean(); then have it email the $test var as the body contents.

Then continue to look at line 401 and then at 469.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known (and reported) issue with `{fileurl}` where the URL gets URL-encoded, leading to URL entities in email notifications.

In the meantime, you can remove the URL-encoding by looking for the following like (around **line 1747**) in **/system/expressionengine/third_party/freeform/default_fields/freeform.ft_file_upload.php**:

```
$url        = urlencode($upload_prefs['url'] . $file_data['filename']);
```

...and changing it to

```
$url        = $upload_prefs['url'] . $file_data['filename'];
```